# Tight bound for a sum of binomial coefficients

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients, approximation, upper-lower-bounds

I am looking for a tight upper bound for the following sum:

$$\sum_{m=1}^k \binom{n}{m} \binom{k-1}{m-1} $$

with $k \leq n$ and $m \leq n$.

Comment: It equals exactly ${n+k-1 \choose k}$ by https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek Are your sure?

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek In fact, any replacement does not give the result.

Answer (score 2):

$$\sum_{m=1}^k{n\choose m}{k-1\choose m-1}=\sum_{m\in\mathbb{Z}}{n\choose m}{k-1\choose m-1}=\sum_{m\in\mathbb{Z}}{n\choose m}{k-1\choose k-m}={n+k-1\choose k}$$

Comment: Thank you for the details!